# Trust Mac on iPad automatically

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad

It is very annoying to "Trust this computer" every time I connect my iPad to Mac.

Is there a way to "trust" my Mac by my iPad automatically?

Comment: Weird. I only had to tap "Trust This Computer" on my iPhone and iPad the first time I connected each one.

Comment: Can you tell me the Version of Mac OS you are running?

Comment: @bMalum I run Yosemity with all the updates.

Comment: Same problem here, but with a Windows machine as the host.  Everytime the iPad is connected (or powered up after being off, while still attached) it prompts me to "Trust".